# Proving that the Euler-Lagrange Equation has no solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle, variational-calculus

I'm trying to show that the Euler - Lagrange equation for the functional $$I(y)=\int_{a}^{b} y\:dx$$

subject to $y(0)=y(1)=0$ has no solutions.

The Euler - Lagrange equation states that:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$$

For this specific problem, $F=y$. Hence, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y'}=0$. So:
$$-\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=0$$

I don't understand why there's **no solution** when one could say that $y=c$, where $c$ is a constant. I understand that $I(y)$ does not have an extremum but how do I prove that the Euler Lagrange equation has no solution?

Comment: What is $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}$ equal to?

Comment: @jacob1729 I mean, $F=y$, so the derivative would just be $1$ and that would lead to $-1=0$ ( as posted below). Does that prove that the Euler - Lagrange equation has no solution ?

Comment: @JimΒ I made my comment before that post. Do you see why that is a contradiction then?

Comment: @jacob1729 yeah I do . Thank you and the OP of the answer below for your input.

Comment: Related Math.SE question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3136864/11127

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\partial F/\partial y$ is not an unknown, it is equal to 1, so your equation is $-1=0$.